# $|Corr(X,Y)|=1$ implies linear relationship a.e. or everywhere?

Tags: probability

The only proof of this implication is using the schwarz inequality, but that only proves that linear relationship for almost everywhere (a.e.), not for all events...

However, in most undergraduate textbooks, they all state that the relationship is as if for all events.

Is there another proof for the case of all events?

Comment: The undergrad texts where you see this might not talk about probability in a measure theoretic context, hence why a.s. results might not be discussed.

Comment: @rubikscube09 you're probably right. Thanks for the comment. ;)